# Filtering the modify event of Watch event on the basis of file attributes

Tags: java, nio

I am listening to watch service in my application.

My app needs to set custom file attributes on the file system during its course of execution. For this also modify event is generated. I don't want to react on these changes.

Is there any way to find out what has actually changed or which attribute has changed in the modify event again ?

Thanks and regards,

Saurav